# How to launch swagger url through vscode?

Tags: visual-studio-code, asp.net-core-webapi, swagger-ui

I am trying to launch swagger UI in browser using dotnet run command. Here is what I have tried in launch.json file. Expected outcome is that it should launch browser at the specified url and open swagger UI automatically. FYI I am using dotnet5 and created new web api project that already has swagger baked in. It doesn't launch the browser.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using **dotnet run** command then its a known limitation that it doesn't launch a browser.

Please [refer to this link](https://github.com/dotnet/sdk/issues/9038) for confirmation

While it doesn't launch it, it will still have your project running just means you manually have to type it in browser or use one of the workarounds listed in that issue.

Comment: I used dotnet watch run and it is able to produce the required result.

Answer (score 15):

```json
"uriFormat": "%s/swagger/index.html"
```

Add the code above in your launch.json.

Example:

```json
{
   "name": ".NET Core Launch (web)",
   "type": "coreclr",
   "request": "launch",
   "preLaunchTask": "build",
   "program": "${workspaceFolder}/{your own project root}",
   "args": [],
   "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}/{your own project root}",
   "stopAtEntry": false,
   "serverReadyAction": {
      "action": "openExternally",
      "pattern": "\\bNow listening on:\\s+(https?://\\S+)",
      "uriFormat": "%s/swagger/index.html"
   },
   "env": {
      "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
   },
   "sourceFileMap": {
      "/Views": "${workspaceFolder}/Views"
   }
},
{
   "name": ".NET Core Attach",
   "type": "coreclr",
   "request": "attach"
}
```

Got this answer from github: https://github.com/dotnet/sdk/issues/9038#issuecomment-1380871802

Comment: serverReadyAction was the helpful piece for me, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Use compounds launch settings

```
"configurations": [
    {
        "name": ".NET Core Launch (console)",
        "type": "coreclr",
        "request": "launch",
        "preLaunchTask": "build",
        "program": "${workspaceFolder}/src/WebApi/bin/Debug/net7.0/YourWebDll.dll",
        "args": [],
        "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
        "stopAtEntry": false,
        "console": "internalConsole"
    },
    {
        "name": "Launch Chrome",
        "request": "launch",
        "type": "chrome",
        "url": "https://localhost:5001/swagger/index.html",
        "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}"
    }
],
"compounds": [
    {
        "name": ".Net Core & Chrome",
        "configurations": [".NET Core Launch (console)","Launch Chrome"]
    }
]
```

This will run your app and launch chrome at the URL you want.